# Pass state to child component - React Tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been following the official React Tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html). And I've reached the point where when I click a square, it calls the Board's handleClick function to update the squares states.
 However, after the states are updated in the Board class, they aren't propagated down to the squares' states.
Here's my code:

```
 class Square extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() =>this.props.onClick()}  >
      {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    };
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
   return <Square value={this.state.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} />;
  }
  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
    handleClick(i) {
  const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
  squares[i] = 'X';
      debugger;
  this.setState({squares: squares});
}
}
```

https://codepen.io/mohamed3on/pen/jVVyWZ?editors=1010
I've followed the tutorial exactly until the "Why Immutability Is Important" part. I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already passing each square's value as a property, but you are trying to pick it up from state in `Square.render()`. You should be using `{this.props.value}`, and lose the state initialization in the constructor, you don't need it. The general pattern is: the *container* component manages state; then the contained components should be stateless. As a general guideline, it is also advisable to avoid using state all along.

Comment: I agree, except for the part "As a general guideline, it is also advisable to avoid using state all along". I see no good reason to discourage using state alltogether. See [gaeron's suggestion on this matter](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978) (in relation to Redux, but viable for use with any other state management library as well).

Comment: Agree. That's what I tried to convey by saying *avoid* and *guideline* instead of never-ever-even-dare-to-think-of-using-or-face-immediate-punishment-by-eternal-excruciating-soul-inflicted-pain. It is definitely explained better in the link you shared. Thank you.